# Get html from <td> and insert it in Select box as selected value

Tags: jquery, html

My Select Box

```
<select id="ProductCode" name="ProductCode">
   <option value="1">Product Description 1 - Box</option>
   <option value="2">Product Description 2 - Carton</option>
   <option value="3">Product Description 3 - Bottle</option>
   <option value="4">Product Description 4 - Cylinder</option>
</select>
```

My td

```
<td>Product Description 3 - Bottle</td>
```

Here I am trying to get the text from  and set the text as selected value in my select box. I am able to get the text from  but unable to insert it into select box.

```
$("#ProductCode").val(<td> text here);
```

Above code doesn't work. Any ideas??? Thanks

Comment: how do you get the value of the option like 1,2,3 etc

Comment: How were you able to get the selected text?
Does your table have an ID or Class?
Please post your complete code or a fiddle

Comment: Infact my question is that only, if I place .val("3") the option is selecting as default but how to do it using just text? Thanks for noticing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var text = $("td").text();
$("#ProductCode").find("option").each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == text){
        $(this).prop("selected",true);
    }
});
```

Comment: the selected option should be set with `prop()` not `attr()`.

Comment: `$(this).prop("selected",true);` not `$(this).attr("selected","selected");`

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
$('#ProductCode option').filter(function(){
  return $(this).html() == text;
}).prop('selected',true);
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/g73rL/

Comment: +1. Maybe also use `this.innerHTML` to save using a method (:

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
    var text= 'Product Description 3 - Bottle';
    $('#ProductCode option:contains(' + text + ')').each(function(){
        if ($(this).text() == text) {
            this.selected = true;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

another way: http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/g73rL/1/

```
var text = "Product Description 2 - Carton"
$('#ProductCode option:contains("' + text + '")').prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily select dropdown option according option text:

```
$("#ProductCode option:contains("+ yourTD_Text +")").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Try this :

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Product Description 1 - Box</td>
    <td>Product Description 2 - Carton</td>
    <td>Product Description 3 - Bottle</td>
    <td>Product Description 4 - Cylinder</td></tr>
</table>


<input id="txtinput" type="text" value="3">    
<input id="btnselect" type="button" value="click here">
    <br/>
<select id="ProductCode" name="ProductCode">
   <option value="1">Product Description 1 - Box</option>
   <option value="2">Product Description 2 - Carton</option>
   <option value="3">Product Description 3 - Bottle</option>
   <option value="4">Product Description 4 - Cylinder</option>
</select>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#btnselect').click(function () {
   var rowNo = $('#txtinput').val().trim();
   var selectOption = $('table tr td:nth-child(' + rowNo + ')').text().trim();     
   $("#ProductCode option:contains("+ selectOption +")").attr('selected', 'selected');
 });
});
```

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uq23C/3/)